# android unchecked radio button which is already checked

Tags: android, radio-button, unchecked

```
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rg"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.radiogroup.MainActivity" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb_true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb_false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

</RadioGroup>
```

i have one radio group
in which i have 2 radio button

now if radio button 1 is selected and if i tap on same radio button(radio button 1) it should be unchecked ..

it should work as**toggle**.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: then take toggle button .Radio button won't serve your purpose if they are in a radio group.

Comment: `radioButton` never gets unchecked by clicking again on it. It gets unchecked only when you check another `radioButton` of same `radioGroup`

Comment: Use check box instead of RadioButton. RadioButton will not uncheck on clicking it again.

Comment: @AnirudhSharma -- what if i dont have radio group than how u will handle it plz explain .,..

Comment: Well the best part is don't use radio buttons at all.Checkboxes are made specifically for these situations.So use them.They'll do just fine.

Comment: i knew that bt my requirement is to use radio only ,...bdw thnx for the suggestions..

Comment: Heyy Query try my code. And Let me know if you have any query

Answer (score 1):

Yes.. It is possible that radio button can work like checkbox

First Declare flags "false"

```
private boolean flagmale = false;
private boolean flagfemale = false;


rdbtnMale.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (rdbtnMale.isChecked()) {
                if (!flagmale) {
                    rdbtnMale.setChecked(true);
                    rdbtnFemale.setChecked(false);
                    flagmale = true;
                    flagfemale = false;
                } else {
                    flagmale = false;
                    rdbtnMale.setChecked(false);
                    rdbtnFemale.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        }
    });


    rdbtnFemale.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (rdbtnFemale.isChecked()) {
                if (!flagfemale) {
                    rdbtnFemale.setChecked(true);
                    rdbtnMale.setChecked(false);
                    flagfemale = true;
                    flagmale = false;
                } else {
                    flagfemale = false;
                    rdbtnFemale.setChecked(false);
                    rdbtnMale.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

This is also possible with one flag..

Comment: If u are using one Flag, then just invert the boolean values in rdbtnFemale.setOnClickListener

Comment: And yes..don't take radio buttons in radio group, instead take two individual radio buttons

Comment: Heyy @Query if this answer solved your problem then mark (✔) it as verified

Answer (score 0):

Use the  below method that show radio button in alert box programatically

```
 Private void SelectLanguageMethod(){


    // Strings to Show In Dialog with Radio Buttons
            final CharSequence[] items = {"English"," Spanish "};

            // Creating and Building the Dialog
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Select The Language");
            builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

            //Your code here

         }
            });
            levelDialog = builder.create();
            levelDialog.show();
        }
```

Comment: if somebody downvotes, then please explain why...@Kat-hat...this has nothing to do with the question. OP just wants to uncheck his checked RadioButton...

Comment: this is just the alternate way to do it dynamically..I am just giving the choice @Opiatefuchs

Comment: Yes sure, but it´s not related to the question. So You should explain a little bit more for OP to understand. Also, this is not give him a solution for his problem..

Comment: I would have to agree with the other downvoters, this is not relevant to the question and does not offer a solution to toggle a radio button.  The OP didn't mention anything about wanting to use a dialog.  I came here looking for an answer to the same problem and the UI specifications that have been given to me are explicit.

Answer (score 0):

This should serve the purpose.

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int id)
    {
    RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton)radioGroup.findViewById(id);

    boolean isChecked = checkedRadioButton.isChecked();

    if (isChecked)
    {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
               checkedRadioButton.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    radioButton = (String) checkedRadioButton.getText();
    checkedRadioButton.setChecked(false);
    }
    else
        checkedRadioButton.setChecked(true);
    }});
```

Also, don't forget to initialize `RadioGroup`

Comment: checkedChange will never get call when you select on same radio button , its only call when you select some other radiobutton of group.

Comment: @Query, I tried this code at my end and then i answered it. It worked perfectly fine.

Comment: if it works fine at yout end thn its great, bt android is saying that checkd change will not call if you click on same radio button again .

Comment: @Query i am facing same issue. which you have mention in last comment .did find any solution for same?